# How to safely remove Spark 2.2.0 and install Spark 2.1.0 instead?

Tags: apache-spark, sparkr

I have recently installed Spark 2.2.0 and started configuration, but unfortunately 2.2.0 does not support sparklyr library yet. What is the safest way to exchange it with 2.1.0?

Comment: what do you mean 2.2 does not support SparkR: https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/sparkr.html

Comment: Sorry for the typo - sparklyr library is still not available for 2.2.0

Comment: I wouldnt downgrade just for sparklyr, they will probably update it very soon. In the meantime you could just use SparkR instead.

Comment: What operating system did you install SparkR on?